# How to use Allure attributes with SpecFlow?

Tags: mstest, specflow, allure

Test report framework [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/) allows to use the next test [attributes](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp-commons/tree/master/AllureCSharpCommons/Attributes):

1. AllureDescriptionAttribute
2. AllureFeaturesAttribute
3. AllureSeverityAttribute
4. AllureStoriesAttribute
5. AllureTitleAttribute

**I want to know if it's possible to use them with SpecFlow (+MsTest).**

Actually I already know how to use the `AllureSeverityAttribute` attribute. To use it it's needed to change allureConfig.json file by adding:

```
"specflow": {
"labels": {
  "owner": "^author:?(.+)",
  "severity": "^(normal|blocker|critical|minor|trivial)"
}
```

And then on a scenario you can add a tag like "@blocker" or "@minor" etc.

But I also really want to use `AllureDescriptionAttribute`.

I also don't understand how `AllureDescriptionAttribute` works as when I add a specific tag to my scenario it doesn't add `AllureDescriptionAttribute` to the .feature.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

About Story, if you will add @Story:dfs, then you will see additional level of filtering in behaviors in Allure report.
About your last question. Nothing is added in generated feature files. How Allure works, AllureLifeCycle is used. In this class all is added, all information is gathered from Scenario (ScenarioContext, tags, etc.) and it creates results, which are understood by Allure command line tools. You also can edit current Test information, using this class, in your code (I am using it to attach links, screenshots, logs).
If you want to get more understand-ability in how Allure works, I would recommend watch it's code in their repository.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers. Maybe you also know how to fix adding of new defect categories using Allure C#? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: About defect categories, hadn't yet tried, didn't have a need in this. Maybe will try in some future :) . But I would try with this place: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_categories_2 . And also would watch in code. Maybe that this is not implemented for Allure.Specflow (had this kind of situations).

Comment: According to the doc, categories.json file doesn't have any connection to SpecFlow. But it doesn't work.) Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you try to copy this file into allure-results before generating report?